# Identifying the aggregate roots

Tags: .net, asp.net, nhibernate, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

http://i51.tinypic.com/2ueqidt.jpg

Let us assume the following relationships (diagram).  A FundCompany has Funds, and Accounts.  There is also a FundAccount which creates a many-to-many relationship (as well as other attributes at the relationship level) between Accounts and Funds.  Lastly an Account has one or more Beneficiary.

The FundCompany is an aggregate root as it’s at the top of the pyramid.  Neither Account nor Fund can exist without the FundCompany.  FundAccount cannot exist without both Fund and Account; does that make them both aggregate roots?  Or is Fund still the only aggregate root, having to go through it to perform operations on FundAccount entities?  The fact that the Account also has Beneficiaries, which cannot exist without the Account, does that also signal Account being an aggregate root?

All of the entities on this diagram will require CRUD operations and screens in my application.  The reason I’m bringing this is up is most often every UI screen will store the ID of the row/entity it’s referencing.  So for example a user clicks “Details” on a table with Funds, I might need to retrieve a fund via its ID.  My understanding is that if an entity needs direct access then it’s an aggregate root in itself.  However this would make a lot of entities aggregate roots by default.

Based on the answers to above questions I have to map these operations to the proper aggregate root’s repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole your diagram is single aggregate = it have single aggregate root - the top level `FundFamily`. If `Fund` and `Account` can't live without `FundFamily` their can't be aggregate roots.

Comment: I only posted a small portion of my model as an example.  However looking at my model I might have 100 entities, all branching down from the FundFamily as the owner of the entire graph, with the tree being possibly 5 levels deep in some spots.  There must be more to identifying aggregate roots than the simplistic "well everything underneath of it can't exist without it".  Otherwise my entire model of 100+ entities collapses to 1 service/repository?

Comment: How are you going to define such graph in UI if you must define all entities in one shoot because you can't save partial data?

Comment: Also, say FundFamily is the only aggregate root on the entire graph, how would I go about writing a "get by id" method for each one of these entities?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, we're sort of talking about what is commonly referred to as the "delete test".  Meaning if you had to delete the FundFamily, you're deleting about 100 entities in my graph.  It's sort of like saying PlanetEarth might have a million entities under it, but without its existence, we're all gone.  So is PlannetEarth the only aggregate root then for everything on earth?

Comment: If you define your domain model this way then yes because PlanetEarth can be part of bigger model.

Comment: Here is an interesting post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845671/what-method-do-you-use-to-identify-the-aggregate-roots-in-domain-drive-design

Comment: Anyway IMO using aggregate roots make sense if you want to load aggregate root and work with its dependent objects not if you want to load and work with each dependent object separately (CRUD).

Comment: So are you saying that DDD is not well suited for CRUD type applications?  Because that's typically what my apps are.

Comment: With your planet example - is building part of planet's aggregate root? Most probably yes because if you destroy planet you will destroy building as well. But is a human part of planet's aggregate root? Probably not because human (sci-fi) can be on other planet ...

Comment: If your CRUD application is mostly something like forms over data = get me this entity by id so I can modify it and save it then my opinion is that you don't need DDD at all. Or at least you don't have to deal with aggregate roots.

Comment: In such case, what organization/pattern do you suggest for Data and Business layers? I am using Entity Framework as an ORM.